# How to work with Azure Devops Server to use Universal Package Task

Tags: gradle, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server

I am working with Azure pipelines where the microservice has a dependency which has different versions.(Example: abc-1.0.1, abc-1.0.2) How should I store those dependency in Azure Devops

I came across The Universal Package task, which is currently not supported with Azure Devops Server. How should be the versioning of packages(created by gradle build) maintained while working with Azure Devops Server.

As currently different versions of build/jar is required by microservices. In order to maintain those versions, names,  what is the best way in Azure Devops. (Note: As mentioned we are working with Azure Devops Server, not Azure Devops Services)

Answer (score 1):

The [**Universal Package task**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops-2020) is not totally unsupported on Azure DevOps Server. It can be available on **TFS 2018**, **Azure DevOps Server 2019** and **Azure DevOps Server 2020**.

[image]

So, if the version of your Azure DevOps Server (TFS) is **TFS 2018** or later, you can use this task in your pipeline as normal.

If your TFS version is lower than **TFS 2018** and does not support using the **Universal Package task**, you can try to call the Azure CLI "[**az artifacts universal**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest)" in the pipeline to publish and download the Universal Packages.

- [**az artifacts universal publish**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#az-artifacts-universal-publish): to publish the Universal Packages to the Artifacts feed.
- [**az artifacts universal download**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/artifacts/universal?view=azure-cli-latest#az-artifacts-universal-download): to download the Universal Packages from the Artifacts feed.

Comment: Hi, when I add Universal Package task to my pipeline yaml, it throws error "##[error]Failed to get artifact tool. Universal Packages are not supported in Azure DevOps Server.
Finishing: UniversalPackages" 
Should I try with az commands in this case ?